# How to convert extracted data into python dictionary?

Tags: python, json, dictionary, elasticsearch

I have data extracted like this. I have to store it in elasticsearch as JSON file. before this, I want it to be converted into a dictionary.
please help.

```
skill = ['Java', 'JavaScript', 'C++'] experience = None
```

multiple similar entries.
..
..
..

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question doesn't have much info. Based on your info given, this may be the solution.

```
skill = ['Java', 'JavaScript', 'C++']
experience = None
data = {}
data['skill'] = skill
data['experience'] = experience

print(data)
#{'skill': ['Java', 'JavaScript', 'C++'], 'experience': None}
```